# Phonegap 3.0 installation issue in Mac

Tags: node.js, npm, phonegap-build

I have already installed Phonegap 2.9.1 on my Mac. Now I want to use the Social media plugin where it is mentioned in that I need phonegap 3.0 and more. Now here comes the issue. As I already have 2.9.1 installed how can I upgrade it to 3.0? I tried to install phonegap 3.0 but getting bunch of issues. I have also upgraded node.js and npm latest version.

Here are the errors

sudo npm install -g npm@latest
Password:
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@2.8.4 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
Amitava-Sinhas-Mac-Pro:~ Amitava$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
npm WARN engine npm@1.4.28: wanted: {"node":">=0.8","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.8.4"})
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.7.3: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.8.4"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.8.4"})
npm WARN deprecated deflate-crc32-stream@0.1.2: module has been merged into crc32-stream

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
npm ERR! not a package /tmp/npm-999-ed1c9e88/github.com/component/bind/archive/0.0.1.tar.gz
npm ERR! Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.8.4
npm ERR! path /tmp/npm-999-ed1c9e88/unpack-ec4f0610c09e/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open '/tmp/npm-999-ed1c9e88/unpack-ec4f0610c09e/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Please any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install latest node.js from here

https://nodejs.org/

Then type the following in terminal:-

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Then start creating Project:-

```
cordova create ~/Desktop/ProjectName com.xyz.xyz DisplayName
```